# Parallel algorithm for Polynomial GCD

Tags: algorithms, parallel-computing

It is known that half-GCD ([https://www.csd.uwo.ca/~mmorenom/CS424/Lectures/FastDivisionAndGcd.html/node6.html](https://www.csd.uwo.ca/%7Emmorenom/CS424/Lectures/FastDivisionAndGcd.html/node6.html)) is can be used to compute the GCD of two polynomials over a finite field. Is it possible to parallelize it? Or, are there any practical polynomial GCD algorithms that can run on clusters (like mpi, Hadoop)?

Comment: What kind of polynomial are you talking about that you want to run it on a cluster? Polynomials with degrees in the millions? In that case I would first look at investigating what happens to your coefficients.

Comment: Yeah, maybe even 10s of millions (univariate polynomials) and they'll be dense polynomials.

Comment: A plausible approach is to use any gcd algorithm (e.g., Euclidean algorithm) with parallel algorithms for polynomial multiplication and division.  I'm not sure whether that will be useful or not.

Comment: I'm wondering ihow much speed up could be achieved. It looks like that half-gcd will make many more calls on "smaller" polynomial mul/div. When the degree is low, the benefits for doing parallel polynomial mul/div would be diminishing.